# Optimisation (linear programming) in Python

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

I am new to optimisation and was trying out an example I made up in Python. My objective is to figure out how much of each component I need to add to mimic the product as closely as possible.

The example that I made goes something like: I get given a product that contains 3 components (x, y, z), these components have values associated with them, but I don't know how much of each component is used to make the final product. One extra condition is that total of the 3 component's values might not match up with final product's values. One constraint I have given myself is that I know how much the product weighs, in this case I made the example 10.

Since the values for the components and the product might not match up, I thought it might be a good idea to use the difference between each value of the total values of the components and the product and then minimise that wrt the original 3 components.

I tired using PuLP to solve this, but I'm unsure how to go about writing a good objective function or even if my idea for the objective function will work.

Some example python code:

```
components = pd.DataFrame({
        "x": [3, 4, 1, 4],
        "y": [0, 2, 1, 4],
        "z": [0, 0, 1, 4],
        "total": [4, 6, 3, 12]
        })

product = pd.DataFrame({
        "product": [4, 2, 6, 12]
        })

difference = product["product"] - components["total"]

# define model
model = LpProblem("test", sense = LpMinimize)

# variables to add to the model to add to the model
component1 = LpVariable("component1", lowBound = 0, upBound = None, cat = "Integer")
component2 = LpVariable("component2", lowBound = 0, upBound = None, cat = "Integer")
component3 = LpVariable("component3", lowBound = 0, upBound = None, cat = "Integer")

# constraints

model += component1 + component2 + component3 == 10

# objective function
# minimise the difference wrt to the 3 components

model.solve()
```

Example output (if this is optimal):

```
component1 = 3
component2 = 6
component3 = 1
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I dont understand the question. Are you asking how to model the problem, or are you asking how to represent the model using PuLP?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm mainly asking how to represent the model using PuLP.

Comment: Sounds doable, but your description is hard to follow, especially when changing descriptions (component_0_1_2 vs. x_y_z) and dimensions: why are there multiple products (building a product out of components should lead to a vector, not a matrix in input)? I highly recommend formalizing this a bit and maybe including a more complete example (which is compatible with dimensions).

Comment: @ijstneedaname Then, if you already know the model, could you write it in mathematical notation first? Such as: `x + y + z = 10`, `x, y, z >= 0`. This would make it easier to help you represent it using PuLP